# bokeh add legend to Step graph

Tags: python, python-3.x, plot, legend, bokeh

How can I add a legend to lines in Step graph example for bokeh:

https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/reference/models/glyphs/step.html

I would like to have legend in 'top right' corner of plot for each line in color and style of the line.

The default code for the example is:

```
import numpy as np


from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource, DataRange1d, Plot, LinearAxis, Grid

from bokeh.models.glyphs import Step

from bokeh.io import curdoc, show


N = 11

x = np.linspace(-2, 2, N)
y = x**2

source = ColumnDataSource(dict(x=x, y1=y, y2=y+2, y3=y+4))

xdr = DataRange1d()
ydr = DataRange1d()

plot = Plot(
    title=None, x_range=xdr, y_range=ydr, plot_width=300, plot_height=300,
    h_symmetry=False, v_symmetry=False, min_border=0,toolbar_location=None)

glyph1 = Step(x="x", y="y1", line_color="#f46d43", mode="before")
plot.add_glyph(source, glyph1)

glyph2 = Step(x="x", y="y2", line_dash="dashed", line_color="#1d91d0", mode="center")
plot.add_glyph(source, glyph2)

glyph3 = Step(x="x", y="y3", line_width=3, line_color="#cab2d6", mode="after")
plot.add_glyph(source, glyph3)

xaxis = LinearAxis()
plot.add_layout(xaxis, 'below')

yaxis = LinearAxis()
plot.add_layout(yaxis, 'left')

plot.add_layout(Grid(dimension=0, ticker=xaxis.ticker))
plot.add_layout(Grid(dimension=1, ticker=yaxis.ticker))

curdoc().add_root(plot)

show(plot)
```

Answer (score 6):

You can add a legend entry for each glyph manually by selecting the corresponding renderer in your plot and then connecting it to a `LegendItem`.
Here's the full code using your example:

```
import numpy as np
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource, DataRange1d, Plot, LinearAxis, Grid, Legend, LegendItem
from bokeh.models.glyphs import Step
from bokeh.io import curdoc, show

N = 11

x = np.linspace(-2, 2, N)
y = x**2

source = ColumnDataSource(dict(x=x, y1=y, y2=y+2, y3=y+4))

xdr = DataRange1d()
ydr = DataRange1d()

p1 = Plot(
    title=None, x_range=xdr, y_range=ydr, plot_width=300, plot_height=300,
    h_symmetry=False, v_symmetry=False, min_border=0, toolbar_location=None)

glyph1 = Step(x="x", y="y1", line_color="#f46d43", mode="before")
p1.add_glyph(source, glyph1)

glyph2 = Step(x="x", y="y2", line_dash="dashed", line_color="#1d91d0", mode="center")
p1.add_glyph(source, glyph2)

glyph3 = Step(x="x", y="y3", line_width=3, line_color="#cab2d6", mode="after")
p1.add_glyph(source, glyph3)

xaxis = LinearAxis()
p1.add_layout(xaxis, 'below')

yaxis = LinearAxis()
p1.add_layout(yaxis, 'left')

p1.add_layout(Grid(dimension=0, ticker=xaxis.ticker))
p1.add_layout(Grid(dimension=1, ticker=yaxis.ticker))


li1 = LegendItem(label='red', renderers=[p1.renderers[0]])
li2 = LegendItem(label='blue', renderers=[p1.renderers[1]])
li3 = LegendItem(label='purple', renderers=[p1.renderers[2]])
legend1 = Legend(items=[li1, li2, li3], location='top_right')
p1.add_layout(legend1)

curdoc().add_root(p1)
show(p1)
```

This should be the result:

[image]

Comment: I tried do this in your way earlier but I din't know how to add legend to layout. Thanks for the solution.

Comment: I stumbled upon a similar problem a while ago. But as @bigreddot said, it's generally better to go with the higher level APIs.

Answer (score 2):

Just for completeness, it's worth mentioning that the code you link is demonstrating the very low level `bokeh.models` API. If that's what you need, that's perfectly fine. But in case you are simply unaware, most usage can be done more simply with the higher level `bokeh.plotting` API:

```
import numpy as np
from bokeh.io import output_file, show
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource
from bokeh.plotting import figure

N = 11
x = np.linspace(-2, 2, N)
y = x**2

source = ColumnDataSource(dict(x=x, y1=y, y2=y+2, y3=y+4))

plot = figure(title=None, plot_width=300, plot_height=300, toolbar_location=None)

plot.step(x="x", y="y1", line_color="#f46d43", mode="before", 
          source=source, legend="step 1")
plot.step(x="x", y="y2", line_dash="dashed", line_color="#1d91d0", mode="center", 
          source=source, legend="step 2")
plot.step(x="x", y="y3", line_width=3, line_color="#cab2d6", mode="after", 
          source=source, legend="step 3")

output_file("plot.html")

show(plot)
```

This code produces the same image as the answer above.

Comment: Thanks. It what exactly I prefer. I just found the example but non of the low level API class (Plot or Step) had the legend attr so I couldn't found the solution. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for help, guys. But in the last example, the framework calls a warning:

```
BokehDeprecationWarning: 'legend' keyword is deprecated, use explicit
'legend_label', 'legend_field', or 'legend_group' keywords instead
```

small changes are necessary:

```
...
plot.step(x="x", y="y1", line_color="#f46d43", mode="before", 
          source=source, legend_label="step 1")
...
```

And for completeness. If you want to change location of legend use for example:

```
plot.legend.location = 'top_left'
```